# Does Solve make internally assumptions about the domain of the variables?

Tags: equation-solving, inverse, inverse-function

I recently tried to invert the innocent looking function

$\frac{x}{(1+\sqrt{1-x})^2}$

So I tried the command

`Solve[x/(1 + Sqrt[1 - x])^2 == y, x]`,

which effectively immediately gives the result

`{{x -> (4 y)/(1 + y)^2}}` .

But now the problems begin. When I tried to verify the solution, it did not work out for all values. Inserting the solution results in

$\frac{4 y}{(1 + y)^2 \left(1 + \sqrt{1 -\frac{4y}{(1 + y)^2} }\right)^2}$,

which does not reduce to y by simple applications of //FullSimplify, //FunctionExpand, //PowerExpand etc. After some playing around, I realized that this expression is actually equal to y only inside of the unit disc, and outside of it to 1/y. So the solution holds only for some values of y and not globally.

I was rather surprised by this behaviour. The same happens if one tries InverseFunction, giving the same answer as Solve (as a function). Any ideas why this is happening or what can be done to obtain the correct solutions (without manually studying the function)? In this case this was rather easely repaired, but in general this can become quite complicated.

Comment: Have you tried `Reduce`? That usually gives more detailed information about these sort of things. Also, `Solve` for me raises a warning message that the solution may not be completely general.

Comment: Reduce gives an unsolved equation. Which version of Mathematica are you using that you get this warning massage? In 12.0 I do not get it. Or is there a setting to produce more warnings? Even if I set the VerifySolutions->True option I do not get any warnings.

Comment: I'm on V12.3 right now.

Comment: At the end of the documentation for `Solve`, under "Possible Issues", you'll see that `Solve` gives "generic solutions", which means they work for most (but not necessarily all) values of the vars and params  [See "Generic and Non-Generic Cases" at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MathematicalFunctions.html#16439 ] To obtain a genl result that includes the restrictions on the vars and params, you can use either `Reduce`, or `Solve` with  the `Method->Reduce` option. [`MaxExtraConditions->All` will give all restrictions on the displayed solns, but not necessarily all solns.]

Comment: Can you formulate that comment as an answer such that I can accept it? The MaxExtraConditions->All option was exactly what I was looking for, in this case it results in a warning that the result depends on the branchcuts.

Comment: Done-turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the documentation for `Solve`, under "Possible Issues", you'll see that `Solve` gives "generic solutions", which means they work for most (but not necessarily all) values of the variables and parameters.

For more on this, see "Generic and Non-Generic Cases" at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MathematicalFunctions.html#16439

To see the restrictions on the parameters and variables, you can use `Solve` with the `MaxExtraConditions->All` option:

```
Solve[x/(1 + Sqrt[1 - x])^2 == y, x, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

[image]

But there are some caveats:

1)`MaxExtraConditions->All` will sometimes prevent `Solve` from giving a solution; in that case, you can instead try `Solve` with the `Method->Reduce` option, or `Reduce`; these will usually (but not always—see below) give a complete solution set with all the restrictions:

```
Solve[x Log[x] == a, x]
Solve[x Log[x] == a, x, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
Solve[x Log[x] == a, x, Method -> Reduce]
Reduce[x Log[x] == a, x]
```

[image]

2)While the documentation (*Solve: Details and Options*) says "With Method->Reduce, Solve uses only equivalent transformations **and finds all solutions**" [emphasis mine], this does not appear to always be the case.  For instance, in the following, `Method->Reduce` misses the solution $x = 1$ when $a = 0$.  This solution is found by `Solve` with the `MaxExtraConditions->All` option, and by `Reduce`:

```
Solve[a x^2 + x == 1, x]
Solve[a x^2 + x == 1, x, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
Solve[a x^2 + x == 1, x, Method -> Reduce]
Reduce[a x^2 + x == 1, x]
```

[image]

3)The above might appear to suggest that you're safest using `Reduce`, since the documentation (*Solve: Possible Issues*) says "Reduce **gives all solutions**, including those that require equations on parameters" [emphasis mine].  However, here's an example in which `Solve` returns a result, while `Reduce`, and `Solve` with `MaxExtraCondtions->All` or `Method->Reduce` do not:

```
Solve[5 == x*2^(x^2), x]
Solve[5 == x*2^(x^2), x, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
Solve[5 == x*2^(x^2), x, Method -> Reduce]
Reduce[5 == x*2^(x^2), x]
```

[image]

We can get the latter three to supply Solve's solution by imposing a domain restriction:

```
Solve[5 == x*2^(x^2) && x \[Element] Reals, x, MaxExtraConditions->All]
Solve[5 == x*2^(x^2) && x \[Element] Reals, x, Method -> Reduce]
Reduce[5 == x*2^(x^2) && x \[Element] Reals, x]
```

[image]

So perhaps it's more accurate to say "When `Reduce` *returns a result*, it gives all solutions; but sometimes `Solve` will return a result when `Reduce` does not".

N.B.: The above were run on:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make a plot of the function (Abs value because it is complex):

```
f[x_] = x/(1 + Sqrt[1 - x])^2;
Plot[Abs@f[x], {x, -2, 2}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

As you can see, the inverse function is multivalued. If you need a single valued function, you must restrict the definition domain.

If you define the inverse function as f1:

```
f1[y_] = 4 y/(1 + y)^2;
f1[f[x]] // Simplify
(* x *)
```

Therefore, this is a true inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @DanielHuber's answer `ContourPlot` visualizes the completeness of the real solution `x==(4 y)/(1 + y)^2`

```
Show[{ContourPlot[x/(1 + Sqrt[1 - x])^2 == y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}] ,
ParametricPlot[{ (4 y)/(1 + y)^2, y}, {y, -1, 1},PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Thickness[.01], Red}]}]
```

[image]